# Rails more than one index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller

I have a model call question and I need 2 index pages for it. One for all the questions and one for all the questions that are official (only the questions that have true for my column "official"). How would I go about doing this. so far i just have the index that returns all questions

```
    def index 
        @questions = Question.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand, that's why I will suggest 2 ways:

1) You can have 2 different urls and views - one for all questions and one for officials

```
def index 
    @questions = Question.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
end

def official 
    @questions = Question.where(official: true).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
end
```

2) If you want to render both lists in one page:

```
def index 
    @all_questions = Question.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
    @official_questions = Question.where(official: true).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
end
```

Comment: for the first one do I need to modify my routes.rb file, currently it is "resources :questions"

Comment: Yes, you should add: `get 'questions/official', to: 'questions#official'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused.

You can do this with *one* `index` method & view. You may have different options for it, but ultimately, you'll have one method with which you'll be able to populate depending on the request you send:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :questions do
   get :official, to: :index, on: :collection, official: "true" #-> url.com/questions/official
end

#app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      if params[:official]
         @questions = Question.where(official: true)
      else
         @questions = Question.all
      end
      @questions = @questions.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
   end
end
```

Then you'd use:

```
#app/views/questions/index.html.erb
<%= render @questions %>

#app/views/questions/_question.html.erb
<%= question.title %>
```

---

You don't need the [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) (I like it because it modularizes what you're doing) - the important thing to note is that you're basically populating `@questions` each time -- the `index` view just serves as a way to view the data it contains.

Thus, you don't need two index methods -- you *can* just set a custom link and use some conditional logic in your controller to determine what data to use.